# JSON response parse two array for a key in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I am getting a json response from server something like this.

```
{
    "List": [{
        "title": "New",
        "type": 1,
        "date": "2016-07-01"
    }, {
        "title": "New1",
        "type": 0,
        "date": "2016-07-01"
    }],
    "List2": [{
        "type": "1",
        "date": "2016-07-01"
    }, {
        "type": "1",
        "date": "2016-07-05"
    }]
}
```

I want to loop through the two arrays using an iteration which starts from a starting date to end date. In it I have to check, if there is an entry for the date in list1 or list2. If so, I have to do some operations. Please help me to do this. I am a beginner .Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = {
    "List1": [{
        "title": "New",
        "type": "1",
        "date": "2016 - 07 - 01"
    }, {
        "title": "New1",
        "type": "0",
        "date": "2016 - 07 - 05"
    }, ],
    "List2": [{
        "type": "1",
        "date": "2016-07-01"
    }, {
        "type": "1",
        "date": "2016-07-05"
    }]
};

var list1 = data.List1;
var list2 = data.List2;

console.log("FOR List 1");
for(var i in list1){
    if(list1[i].date === undefined){
    console.log("No Date");
  }else{
  console.log(list1[i].date);
  }
}

console.log("FOR List 2");
for(var i in list2){
    if(list2[i].date === undefined){
    console.log("No Date");
  }else{
  console.log(list2[i].date);
  }
}
```

> Updated:

```
var data = {
    "List1": [{
        "title": "New",
        "type": "1",
        "date": "2016 - 07 - 01"
    }, {
        "title": "New1",
        "type": "0",
        "date": "2016 - 07 - 05"
    }, ],
    "List2": [{
        "type": "1",

    }, {
        "type": "1",

    }]
};

var list1 = data.List1;
var list2 = data.List2;

console.log("FOR List 1");
var isDateAvailInList1 = false;
for(var i in list1){
    if(list1[i].date === undefined){
    continue;
  }else{
    isDateAvailInList1 = true;
    break;
  }
}
console.log("FOR List 2");
var isDateAvailInList2 = false;
for(var i in list2){
    if(list2[i].date === undefined){
    continue;
  }else{
    isDateAvailInList2 = true;
    break;
  }
}

if(isDateAvailInList1==false){
console.log("No Date in list1");
 //Do the operation when no date in list1
}
if(isDateAvailInList2==false){
console.log("No Date in list2");
 //Do the operation when no date in list2
}
```

[FIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/b6q20e0h/)

Answer (score 0):

You could generate a hash table and then you could easily check if a date is in your object with

```
if (hash['2016-07-01']) {
    // check other things ...
}
```

```js
var object = { "List": [{ "title": "New", "type": 1, "date": "2016-07-01" }, { "title": "New1", "type": 0, "date": "2016-07-01" }], "List2": [{ "type": "1", "date": "2016-07-01" }, { "type": "1", "date": "2016-07-05" }] },
    hash = {};

Object.keys(object).forEach(function (k) {
    object[k].forEach(function (a) {
        hash[a.date] = hash[a.date] || {};
        hash[a.date][k] = a;
    });
});

console.log(hash);
```